# Do you need to seasonally adjust covariates prior to ARIMAX modelling?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, seasonal-adjustment

I found lots of answers in regards to how handle seasonality in dependent variable (time series) though can’t find a definitive answer if we need to seasonally adjust the covariates as well?

My main focus would be ARIMAX and Multiple OLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a common misconception but neither OLS nor ARIMAX places ANY restrictions on the covariates in order for the usual estimators to have the expected distribution. So, no, it is not, a priori, *necessary* to seasonally adjust the covariates.

The restrictions are placed on the *error term*. In particular, that it must be independent and identically distributed, which also means that you should not have seasonal residuals. So, if you take:

$Y_t = a + bX_t + \varepsilon_t$

If $Y_t$ is not seasonal, but $X_t$ is, then usually the residuals will also be seasonal. Depending on the exact situation, you might then want to augment this model with seasonal dummies, or pre-adjust $X_t$, or something like that.

But you might also have that both $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are seasonal in a common way such that the residuals aren't, in which case there isn't any need to do anything special.

Comment: Thank you so much!